# is it possible to make a query lookup for given model inheritance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Below are my models and I am using `InheritanceManager` of `django-model-utils`. i decided the field `user` to be in the subclasses because i need to access the `Child` subclass via the relation like `user.child1_set.all()`.

```
class Mother(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()

class Child1(Mother):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User)

class Child2(Mother):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User)
```

the problem is, when i want to query starting from `Mother` class, there seems to be no query that makes it.

i've tried these codes.

```
Mother.objects.filter(user=SOMEUSER)
Mother.objects.filter(child1__user=SOMEUSER)
Mother.objects.select_subclasses().filder(user=SOMEUSER)
Mother.objects.select_subclasses().filder(child1__user=SOMEUSER)
```

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can query on fields that are only available on the children. Imagine one child class has no `user` field. What should Django query for there? Try moving the `user` field to the parent. If that doesn't help, I'd look though the source of the InheritanceManager.